# Regexp split key values into columns in Bigquery

Tags: regex, dictionary, google-bigquery

My column data looks like

"dayparts": [{"day": "Saturday", "hours": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]}, {"day": "Sunday", "hours": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]}, {"day": "Thursday", "hours": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]}]

I would like to have the result like

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try:

```
WITH sample AS (
SELECT "1" AS id, "{\"dayparts\":[{\"day\":\"Saturday\",\"hours\":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]},{\"day\":\"Sunday\",\"hours\":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]},{\"day\":\"Thursday\",\"hours\":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]}]}" AS msg
)
SELECT id,
    JSON_VALUE(dparts, '$.day') AS day,
    JSON_QUERY(dparts, '$.hours') AS hours
FROM (
SELECT id,
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(JSON_QUERY(msg, '$.dayparts')) AS dayparts
FROM sample) t, UNNEST(t.dayparts) dparts
```

(I added enclosing "{" and "}" to be able to perform JSON operations, if they are not there just concatenate them I guess)
(You can also add "JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY" around "JSON_QUERY(dparts, '$.hours')" if you wish an actual array in the result table)